# Rails: files path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Theoretical question: If I'm making a directory Dir.mkdir('/test'), will this directory be created as /app/test or /public/test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be created as `test` under the root path (`/`) of your filesystem because you're specifying an absolute path (and most likely it will fail because of permission problems).

Use `Dir.mkdir('app/test')` or `Dir.mkdir('public/test')` respectively.